# How do questions become 'hot questions'?

Tags: discussion

I click on the left hand corner from time to time and see the 'hot questions' list.

I'm wondering how questions actually end up there?

Do you have to submit them somewhere?

Or earn a certain amount of views/rep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SE engine has an algorithm to calculate the hotness of a question. All you have to do is ask a good question and depending on the number of views, votes, number of answers and some other parameters the hotness score will be calculated.

here are some discussions that you might find interesting.

[What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions?lq=1)

[How are questions in the 'hot' tab selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected?lq=1)

Comment: Cool, thanks. That answered it perfectly.

Comment: @D3C4FF: So really just a slightly nerdier method of Hot or Not.